# Whats the cause for the error :org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement:

Tags: appium, appium-android

Could someone help me fix the error:

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement:"

It seems like this issue is persistent across most versions . I have the following versions and the error occurs when I try to automate android app by switching to webview.

- Appium :1.14
- Java clent :7.2
- java version "1.8.0_221"
- selenium version in java client 7.2 is 3.141

Answer (score 0):

That meanes that you, for example, trying to `sendKeys` to an element that has no text field, or you try to click on element that is not clickable etc. There are a lot of possibilities of such behavior. You better paste your code that throws such exception